# Log4Net events on log creation and writing to log FileAppender

Tags: c#, log4net

I am wondering if Log4Net 1.2.13.0 exposes any events that can be subscribed to when it creates or writes to a log file. I am using the FileAppender. Googling for such an answer has been hard as event log is often found instead of a C# event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question after doing more research is that the FileAppender class itself does not expose events on logging. Instead you have to create a custom appender that fires an event in the append method and then subscribe to that.